# What is the difference between ActionListener and ActionEvent for a button?

Tags: java

I know this is a really noob of a question but I have recently started to learn Java. I am not really sure what does an ActionEvent do and what does the Action listener does.

Comment: Read [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: [This might help](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: It's the difference between Listening and Speaking. (This should be fairly apparent after following a tutorial/trail or writing a simple program that utilizes Swing/AWT events.)

Answer (score 7):

Let's take a Shop owner in his/her shop monitoring his/her employees.

If the shop owner arrived to the shop, he will start monitoring his employees(which means he has started to observe them waiting for an Event to happen, which is what an **ActionListener** does).

If the shop owner catches an employee sleeping on his shift, he will take action to the event(**ActionEvent**), perhaps firing them or giving them a warning(**Action**).

now back to java.

To declare an actionListener in the class, you either implement ActionListener (ActionListener is an Interface ) and add the method :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
```

}

or you can add the actionListener directly to the JComponent like :

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // action goes here.
```

}
})

Answer (score 1):

An `ActionListener` listens for `ActionEvents`. An `ActionEvent` is something that happens; an `ActionListener` is something that responds to it.

Answer (score 1):

An `ActionListener` is an object listening for an action to occur, such as something being clicked.

An `ActionEvent` is the event that occurred.  So say you click on a JButton, an ActionEvent is fired containing the object that the event occurred to, and some other info.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

An **ActionEvent** is an object that represents the event that occurs when a user clicks on a button.

An **ActionListener** is an interface that deﬁnes the (`actionPerformed()`), which handles **ActionEvents**

hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

A **ActionEvent** is send to a **ActionListener**. For example: If you have a button, and this button is being pressed. A signal form the button will be sent as a ActionEvent. If you then have a ActionListener for that button, that event can be handled by the ActionListener for that button.